# Getting nodes from paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a path that returns a number of, well, paths. `nodes(path)` looks like:

```
[a, b, c, d],
[a, b, e],
[a, f]
```

What I want is to get all the nodes. So converting that path to

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

would be great. I would like to continue using the nodes in further cypher statements so leaving them in a collection doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

EDIT 1

```
MATCH(t:THING1 {id:"t1"})-[:AFFECTS]->(x:SOME_NODE), (t)-[:CHANGES]->(SOME_NODE)
MATCH p=shortestpath((s)-[MY_RELATION*0..4]->(x))
WITH collect(nodes(p)) as nodes
WITH REDUCE(output = [], r IN nodes | output + r) AS flat
```

This produces a collection of nodes. Now to convert it into rows and dedup it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just unwind the collections of nodes from the paths and then return the distinct ones.

```
MATCH(t:THING1 {id:"t1"})-[:AFFECTS]->(x:SOME_NODE), (t)-[:CHANGES]->(SOME_NODE)
MATCH p=shortestpath((s)-[MY_RELATION*0..4]->(x))
UNWIND nodes(p) as n
RETURN DISTINCT n
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks. I had forgotten about UNWIND.